Информация о зафиксированной/отменённой транзакции Postgres(Greenplum)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то аналог pg_stat_activity для уже завершённых транзакций?
Цель: получить user_name автора завершённой транзакции по её id (взятого из xmin, xmax строк таблиц)?
Greenplum 6 Postgres 9.4.24
